# accepts_nested_attributes_for :destroy_if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a :reject_if case for accepts_nested_attributes_for in a class, but I would also like to be able to destroy objects that were already created if a certain value is 0.

There doesn't seem to be a :destroy_if option. Is there a standard way to control cases like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using before_save. This seems to work pretty well.

```
before_save :mark_entries_for_removal

def mark_entries_for_removal
  entries.each do |entry|
    entry.mark_for_destruction if entry.hours_spent <= 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested model is destroyed when its attribute `_destroy` is set (1 or true)

A solution is to overload `your_nested_model_attributes=` to set the `_destroy` attribute to `1`